# Dynamically register to JMS Queue using Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, activemq-classic, spring-jms

This is the thing. I can consume an ActiveMQ queue with the following configuration:

```
 <jms:listener-container
  container-type="default"
  connection-factory="connectionFactory"
  acknowledge="auto">
<jms:listener destination="TEST.FOO" ref="simpleMessageListener" method="onMessage" />
```

Here I am consumming the queue "TEST.FOO", but I would like to consume a queue per user, not a general for all users, is there a way to do that?.

I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I did this:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
                final UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                    public void configure() {               
                        from("activemq:"+userDetails.getUsername()).routeId(userDetails.getUsername()).to("bean:queueHandler");
                    }
                });             
                camelContext.start();
```